# Is it possible to make the variable read-only in the Run-pipeline menu?

Tags: gitlab-ci

[image]

In my .gitlab-ci.yml, I declare MY_VAR1 under variables with a description. Then when I click run-pipeline, I can see my variable is correctly shown with its name as MY_VAR1 and its value as "variable a".
I would like to make the variable's name MY_VAR1 to readonly so that user can only change the value but not the name of the variable.
is there a way to do it ?

```
variables:
  MY_VAR1:
    value: "variable a"
    description: "description a...."
```

Comment: Remove description.

Comment: A GitLab pipeline variable is just a simple *environment variable*. Knowing this, you might want to read: [Is there anyway to set a readonly environment variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/66627/269048).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Janez Kuhar, what I concern the most is the UI interface when user fills up the value of the variables before runing the pipeline. It would be great if the name of the variable is shaded as readonly.